# Does William Wilberforce side with George's son?

Tags: madness-of-king-george

In the [1994 movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110428/) [The Madness of King George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Madness_of_King_George), with [Nigel Hawthorne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Hawthorne), we [see a scene](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/m/madness-of-king-george-script.html) where George's son is conspiring with Parliamentarians to become Princes Regent.

> Regent?
>
> King in all but name.
>
> With all the powers.
>
> Subject to Parliament.
>
> Charles, don't quibble.
>
> And certainly... all the funds.
>
> Ha ha ha ha.
>
> Just think of it.
>
> Regent!
>
> Prime minister.
>
> America forgiven.
>
> London rebuilt.
>
> Parliament could be reformed.
>
> A palace on Primrose Hill.
>
> The slave trade abolished.

Now the slave trade and its reform was an issue at the time - but the specific person driving it was [William Wilberforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Wilberforce). Whilst reform is good, it seemed odd to depict such a noble fellow in such a craven conspiratorial camp.

**In The Madness of King George - Does William Wilberforce side with George's son?**